# Открытие модального окна через ссылку, а не кнопку yii2

Tags: yii2

Подскажите, как реализовать открытие модального окна по ссылке, а не по кнопке,
В шаблоне main   `['label' => 'Создать заявку',  'url' => ['/requests/create']]`

Модальное окно _form.php:

```
<?php
```

Modal::begin([

```
'title'=>'<h5>Создать заявку</h5>',
'id'=>'requests-modal',
'toggleButton' => [
    'label' => 'Создать заявку',
    'tag' => 'button',
    'class' => 'btn btn-success',
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через jQuery (или на JS), добавить событие на ссылку и открывать модальное окно

```
$('body').on('click', '#ид ссылки', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#requests-modal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Можете написать в какое место я должен добавить событие на ссылку и данный код? Я новичок в Yii2, только разбираюсь с ним.

Comment: В assets указывается js для всего проекта или можно создать assets для конкретной области, также можно подключать js файлы в контроллере или в представление, но это частный случай, нужно смотреть по обстоятельствам

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/structure-assets

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался